# Jenkins Docker session timeout configuration

Tags: xml, jenkins, continuous-integration, devops

I am trying to configure SessionEvictionPolicy Parameter from Jenkins on this file:
/jenkins_home/war/WEB-INF/web.xml

The current configuration of the  section is:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>10800</session-timeout>
    <session-eviction>10800</session-eviction>
</session-config>
```

The session-timeout gets the correct value, but the session eviction does not!
I would like to know if this is the correct name of the parameter: session-eviction
If anyone is familiar with it that would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Jenkins server is running on Docker.
I have added this ENV section to the Dockerfile:

```
ENV JENKINS_OPTS --httpPort=<some_value> --httpsPort=<some_value> 
--sessionTimeout=2880 --sessionEviction=172800
```

It will produce long sessions with length of 2 days instead of 30 mins (which is the default for Jenkins).

Pay attention that if you are making any Docker inheritance then the last one values is the JENKINS_OPTS that will affect your Jenkins server!!

If you would like to set the same for Docker-Compose you should add:

```
    environment:
      - TZ=Asia/Jerusalem
      - "JENKINS_OPTS= --httpPort=<some_value> --httpsPort=<some_value> 
--sessionTimeout=2880 --sessionEviction=172800"
```

Note that if you have JENKINS_OPTS on your Dockerfile and on your docker-compose the compose overrides the data of the Dockerfile!

Note that sessionTimeout is in minuets while sessionEviction is in seconds!

For checking if it worked:
On your Jenkins log in as an admin --> Manage Jenkins --> Script Console

```
import org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler;
sess = Stapler.getCurrentRequest().getSession();
printf("sessionTimeout: %d seconds\n", sess.getMaxInactiveInterval());
printf("sessionEviction: %d seconds\n", sess.getSessionHandler().getSessionCache().getEvictionPolicy());
```